# Why is Reset function setting wrong value?

Tags: c#

I'm supposed to write a LIFO (last in first out) class for chars, which can be edited by Pop and Add functions and seen by Peek function or foreach. Class is working on array to be more optimalized, but foreach for some reason's not working. I tried to make function GetEnumerator based on return value of _arr.GetEnumerator() function, but it was not working, because when I printed item, in console was shown TestApp.LIFO, so I made this, but now foreach won't print a single item and by debuging _i value on Reset function is 0. Can someone say why is it happening and suggest solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestApp {
    internal class LIFO : IEnumerator, IEnumerable {
        public LIFO(int size) {
            _arr = new char[size];
            _index = 0;
        }

        public LIFO(char[] arr) {
            _arr = arr.Clone() as char[];
            _index = 0;
        }

        public char Peek() => _index == 0 ? '\0' : _arr[_index - 1];

        public bool Add(char c) {
            if (_index == _arr.Length)
                return false;

            try {
                _arr[_index] = c;
            } catch (Exception) {
                return false;
            }

            ++_index;

            return true;
        }

        public void Pop() {
            if (_index == 0)
                return;

            _arr[--_index] = '\0';
        }

        private int _i;

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => this;
        public bool MoveNext() => --_i > -1;

        public void Reset() => _i = _index - 1;
        public object Current => _arr[_i];

        private int _index;

        private readonly char[] _arr;

    }
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace TestApp {
    internal static class Program {
        private static void Main() {
            LIFO l = new(17);

            l.Add('k');
            l.Add('h');
            l.Add('c');

            foreach (var item in l)
                Console.WriteLine(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should just step through your code to figure out what is happening.  The debugger is your best friend

Comment: yeah, but it ends with reset function, after then, foreach ends and program returns 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Reset` is not called. It is no longer needed but the interface is not changed due to backwards compatibility. Since new iterators implemented using `yield return` is actually required to throw an exception if `Reset` is called, no code is expected to call this method anymore.

As such, your iterator index variable, `_i`, is never initialized and stays at 0. The first call to `MoveNext` steps it below 0 and then returns `false`, ending the `foreach` loop before it even started.

You should always decouple the iterators from your actual collection as it should be safe to enumerate the same collection twice in a nested manner, storing the index variable as an instance variable in your collection prevents this.

You can, however, simplify the enumerator implementation vastly by using [yield return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) like this:

```
public class LIFO : IEnumerable
{
    ...

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = _index - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            yield return _arr[i];
    }
}
```

You can then remove the `_i` variable, the `MoveNext` and `Reset` methods, as well as the `Current` property.

If you first want to make your existing code working, with the above note I made about nesting enumerators, you can change your `GetEnumerator` and `Reset` methods as follows:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    Reset();
    return this;
}

public void Reset() => _i = _index;
```

Note that you have to reset the `_i` variable to one step past the last (first) value as you're decrementing it inside `MoveNext`. If you don't, you'll ignore the last item added to the LIFO stack.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much, however if I'm printing items in foreach, it still writes TestApp.LIFO, but I need to print out the actual chars, do you know what to do about it?

Comment: Yes, use `Console.WriteLine(item);` instead of `Console.WriteLine(l);`. You're essentially printing `Console.WriteLine(l.ToString());` which by default turns out to be the full type name of the object.

Comment: Ah, no, you're not :) I've stared myself almost blind looking at some code until someone points out the *obvious* flaw :)

Answer (score 0):

Your index counter variable using get values in _arr array (it is _i) and index varible that doing increase and decrease operations on it (it is _index) are different. Because of that your for loop never iterate your collection. I fix the code with some addition here. I hope it's helpful.

LIFO.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestApp
{
    internal class LIFO : IEnumerator, IEnumerable
    {
        public LIFO(int size)
        {
            _arr = new char[size];
            _index = 0;
        }

        public LIFO(char[] arr)
        {
            _arr = arr.Clone() as char[];
            _index = 0;
        }
        public int Count() => _index;
        public char Peek() => _index == 0 ? '\0' : _arr[_index - 1];

        public bool Add(char c)
        {
            if (_index == _arr.Length)
                return false;

            try
            {
                _arr[_index] = c;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            ++_index;

            _i = _index;

            return true;
        }

        public void Pop()
        {
            if (_index == 0)
                return;

            _arr[--_index] = '\0';
            _i = _index;
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => (IEnumerator)this;
        public bool MoveNext() => --_index > -1;
        public void Reset() => _index = _i;
        public object Current
        {
            get => _arr[_index];
        }

        private int _index;
        private int _i;
        private readonly char[] _arr;

    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            LIFO l = new LIFO(17);

            l.Add('k');
            l.Add('h');
            l.Add('c');
            Console.WriteLine("Count: " + l.Count());

            foreach (var i in l)
                Console.WriteLine(i);

            l.Reset();
            foreach (var i in l)
                Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
    }
}
```